# What does the dollar sign ($) mean in x86 assembly when calculating string lengths like "$ - label"?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel-syntax

For example, if we were writing a simple hello world type program, the .data section might contain something like:

```
section .data

msg     db      'Enter something: '
len     equ     $ - msg
```

What does the $ in this example represent, and why does `$ - msg` equal the length of the string?

Comment: @James: Nope, there they talk about a different use of the `$` sign.

Answer (score 31):

In this case, the $ means the current address according to the assembler. $ - msg is the current address of the assembler minus the address of msg, which would be the length of the string.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what the assembler refers to as the "current address". By "current address" do you mean "the last statement compiled" (which would be `msg   db   'Enter something: '`)?

Comment: @Terribad - The assembler counts the number of bytes put into the section so far. `$` is where the next one is going.

Answer (score 9):

**NASM documentation**

http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5

> NASM supports two special tokens in expressions, allowing calculations to involve the current assembly position: the $ and $$ tokens. $ evaluates to the assembly position at the beginning of the line containing the expression; so you can code an infinite loop using JMP $.

http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.4

> EQU defines a symbol to a given constant value: when EQU is used, the source line must contain a label. The action of EQU is to define the given label name to the value of its (only) operand. This definition is absolute, and cannot change later. So, for example,
>
> ```
> message         db      'hello, world' 
> msglen          equ     $-message
> ```
>
> defines msglen to be the constant 12

Answer (score 7):

$ is used to refer to the current address and $$ is used to refer to the address of the start  of current section in assembly.

example:

```
section .text
  Mov A,0x0000
  Mov B,0x0000
  Mov C,0x0000
```

for 3rd line $ refers to the address of the line itself while $$ refers to the address of the 1st line (where our section started).
This convention works for me in nasm.

source:[nasm.us](http://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html)

Comment: This is not correct. The double dollar sign (`$$`) refers to the start of the current section, _not_ the previous statement.