# Intel 8086 string reversal

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I found this string manipulation code on the internet, that is used to reverse the contents of a string. Can anyone explain how the length of the string is determined, what does the dollar signify in any sort of string program?

```
model small
.stack 100h  
.data  
String1 db 'assembly language program', $  
Length dw $-String1-1  
.code  
Main proc  
MOV AX, @data  
MOV DS, AX  
MOV SI, offset String1  
MOV CX, Length  
ADD SI, CX  
Back: MOV DL, [SI]  
MOV AH, 02H  
INT 21H  
DEC SI  
LOOP Back  
MOV AH, 4CH  
INT 21H  
End
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the dollar sign ($) mean in x86 assembly when calculating string lengths like "$ - label"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361231/what-does-the-dollar-sign-mean-in-x86-assembly-when-calculating-string-lengt)

Comment: A much better question would be "What's the purpose of `$` in `db 'assembly language program', $` ?" That one has me puzzled... C sriings are null-terminated, Pascal keeps the length at start. Who adds the byte with lenght(?) at end?

Comment: assembly language syntax is defined by the assembler (not the target) so this is not so much an 8086 question but a I have some assembler (a program like masm, nasm, gas) and what does this syntax mean.  What software are you using?

Comment: @Arkadiy take a look at http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21-9.html it looks like somebody mixed different usages of `$` sign

Comment: @Lashane, sorry, don't see the answer there... The `$` there seems to be a literal dollar sign.

Comment: @Arkadiy right, so it looks like original author of the OP's code mixed $ as "here" and $ as string terminator

Comment: @Lashane Aha! Thanks, never ran into that one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481344/dollar-terminated-strings

Comment: @Arkadiy CP/M hat a system call to print a dollar-terminated string and DOS copied it. It's a really weird design.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> String1 db 'assembly language program', $  
> Length dw $-String1-1
> ```

You got 2 $-signs in this program, each with another meaning.

- The 1st $ is a string terminator symbol as required by the DOS string output function 09h. Usually this would have to be written as `...program','$'` or simply included with the rest of the string `...program$'`.
- The 2nd $ is a special assembler symbol that represents the current address. So no matter what line the assembler is at, the $ has the current address.

Let's focus on the 2nd case.

In the line `String1 db 'assembly...'`, the user defined symbol *String1* represents the address where the string starts in memory. When the assembler subsequently processes the line `Length dw ...`, the **$** has the address of this line and as a consequence also the address of the end of the previous line (Both are the same).
Since we know where the string starts (*String1*) and where it ends (*$*) a simply subtraction is enough to determine the length using `Length dw $-String1`.
An additional 1 is subtracted because we don't want the string terminating $ character to be included in the count! `Length dw $-String1-1`

---

**Be careful with what you found on the internet!** This program is wrong. It mistakenly includes the terminating $ character but forgets to use the 1st character of the string.

Next code solves the problem:

```
    MOV  SI, offset String1  
    MOV  CX, Length 
    ADD  SI, CX
Back:
    DEC  SI
    MOV  DL, [SI]
    MOV  AH, 02h
    INT  21h
    LOOP Back
```