# What does double dollar sign mean in x86 assembly (NASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

The expression is:

```
times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

I know what the dollar sign means but I don't know what it means when it's double.

What does the double dollar sign mean?

Comment: Future readers: for `$`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361231/what-does-the-dollar-sign-mean-in-x86-assembly-when-calculating-string-lengt.  (One of the answers there mentions `$$` too.)

Answer (score 26):

When all else fails, Read The [Fine Manual](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.13.01/nasmdoc.pdf) (section 3.5 "Expressions"):

> NASM supports two special tokens in expressions, allowing calculations to involve the current assembly position: the $ and $$ tokens. $ evaluates to the assembly position at the beginning of the line containing the expression; so you can code an infinite loop using JMP $. $$ evaluates to the beginning of the current section; so you can tell how far into the section you are by using ($−$$).

So the example in your question is just padding the current section to a size of 512 with zeroes.

Comment: Are you aware of how this could be done in GAS? -- Looks like you can. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859273/calculating-padding-length-with-gas-att-directives-for-a-boot-sector) question.

Answer (score 0):

$$ evaluates to the beginning of the current section. you could find it in nasm documentation here : https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5