# How to do the equivalent of "times 512-($-$$) db 0" (nasm) in gas (gnu assembler)

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, gnu-assembler, osdev

In nasm (Netwide Assembler), it is possible to find the address of the current instruction with *$*, and the address of the current section with *$$*.  By using *($-$$)* we therefore get the length of the section so far, and with the full instruction:

```
times 512-($-$$) db 0
```

we pad the remainder of a sector with zeros.
This is typically used in small hello-world programs for OS development.

I have seen that GNU assembler supports constructs like *rept* to make repetions, and *.* (dot) can be used to get the current address. But I have not yet figured out exactly how to do the whole *thing* in gas.

So how can it be done?

Comment: Possibly this answer is what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47859400/3857942

Comment: Have you tried `.space 512-(.-begin)` where `begin` is an appropriately defined label?  Though, this sort of problem is better solved with a linker script.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! It seems like a duplicate of the question you link to. Hopefully my way of phrasing the question should make it easier for others to find this answer via search engines.