# Obtaining the address of the current section in GNU Assembly without $$

Tags: assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

The [NASM Documentation](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5) describes the special tokens `$` and `$$`:

> NASM supports two special tokens in expressions, allowing calculations
>   to involve the current assembly position: the $ and $$ tokens. $
>   evaluates to the assembly position at the beginning of the line
>   containing the expression; so you can code an infinite loop using JMP
>   $. $$ evaluates to the beginning of the current section; so you can
>   tell how far into the section you are by using ($-$$).

I understand how to overcome the lack of `$` in GNU Assembly - by declaring a label on the preceding line and using its address:

```
xgrndsize      equ     $ - xgrnd
```

becomes:

```
xgrnd_end:
                .set       xgrndsize, xgrnd_end - xgrnd
```

How can I obtain the address of the current section without `$$`?

Comment: GAS has `.` instead of `$`.  It's not a lack, just different syntax.  (I'm not sure about an equivalent for `$$`, though.)  Related: [Calculating padding length with GAS AT&T directives for a boot sector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859273/calculating-padding-length-with-gas-att-directives-for-a-boot-sector) shows an example of `.space 510-(.-_start)` as an alternative to `$ - $$`.

Comment: I don't think you can get the current section, but you can get any section's address by using its name.