# How does $$ and $ in nasm translate to Gnu Assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, gnu-assembler

In NASM I can write `jmp $` and use `($-$$)`, but what is the equivalent in GNU Assembler (GAS).

Comment: `$` would be [`.`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Dot.html), but I don’t think `$$` has a direct equivalent. You’d have to know which section you’re in.

Comment: Is this a bootloader (I'm guessing it is, and your other question today confirms it)? After your last line of code and data in the bootloader you can do an `.org 510` and then do a `.word 0xaa55`. Otherwise you might have to look at doing it in a linker script. The answers to this question might be of some use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47859273/calculating-padding-length-with-gas-att-directives-for-a-boot-sector and might be a duplicate.