# What does $ in CJNE and SJMP in 8051 assembly mean?

Tags: assembly, 8051, dollar-sign

I see `$` in SJMP, CJNE and other instructions in 8051 assembly code and don't know what it does. Here

```
CJNE A,#'A',$+5   
SJMP $
```

Can you tell me the purpose of it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a special label indicating the current line. `SJMP $` is equivalent to

```
currentline: SJMP currentline
```

And `CJNE A,#'A',$+5` will jump to the instruction 5 bytes ahead when the condition matches

- [Embedded Systems Design with 8051 Microcontrollers: Hardware and Software](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=YiTa-HChn0UC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=dollar%20sign%208051%20assembly&source=bl&ots=Bdf5P3jQYK&sig=ACfU3U0XJescu3n0MWhmqyvxYZDgVR1PEg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQt4Gm6anhAhWRxosBHT7bCN04ChDoATABegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=dollar%20sign%208051%20assembly&f=false)
- [What does "SJMP $" mean in Assembly language?](http://www.8051projects.net/t17365/8051-discussion-forum/sjmp.htm)
- [What is the meaning of the dollar sign in the assembly program of 8051?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-the-dollar-sign-in-the-assembly-program-of-8051)
- ftp://www.raisonance.com/pub/Support/RKit-51/MA51.pdf
- [assembly language help regarding $ sign](https://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?193448-MOVED-assembly-language-help-regarding-sign)

In fact it's the same as the dollar sign in assembly languages for many other architectures

- [What does the dollar sign ($) mean in x86 assembly when calculating string lengths like "$ - label"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10361231/995714)